# Rails: Creating a value object with a validated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two model that both have identical states (Draft, Live, Inactive).  I liked the idea of DRY'ing my code through a value object.  I created the following code:

```
class CurrentStatus
  STATUSES = %w"DRAFT LIVE INACTIVE"
  attr_reader :status

  def initialize(status)
    stringed_status = status.to_s
    if STATUSES.include?(stringed_status)
      @status = stringed_status
    else
      raise "Invalid state for object Status"
    end
  end
end
```

And in the model:

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  composed_of :status, :class_name => 'CurrentStatus', :mapping => %w(status)
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :status
```

This allows me to successfully perform:

```
[47] pry(main)> i = Interest.new
=> #<Interest id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, status: nil>
[49] pry(main)> i.status = CurrentStatus.new('blech')
RuntimeError: Invalid state for object Status from /app/models/current_status.rb:10:in `initialize'
[50] pry(main)> i.status = CurrentStatus.new('DRAFT')
=> DRAFT
[51] pry(main)> i
=> #<Interest id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, status: "DRAFT">
```

but not:

```
[48] pry(main)> i.status = 'DRAFT'
NoMethodError: undefined method `status' for "DRAFT":String
from ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord- 3.2.13/lib/active_record/aggregations.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in writer_method'
```

So when in InterestsController I call the new method:

```
  def new
    @interest = Interest.new
```

and pull up the form:

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :status %><br />
      <%= f.select(:status, %w"DRAFT REPORT_ONLY LIVE SUSPENDED" ) %>
```

My validation stops me:

```
  Rendered interests/_form.html.erb (70.1ms)
  Rendered interests/new.html.erb within layouts/application (83.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 465ms

RuntimeError - Invalid state for object Status:
  app/models/current_status.rb:10:in `initialize'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/aggregations.rb:229:in `block in reader_method'
```

What's a better way for me to write this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help materialdesigner.  I also sent this out to some friends.  Your answer got me partway there as did theirs.

They convinced me to get rid of 'composed_of' since the word is it may be deprecated.  I took your advice and used ActiveModel::Validations.  Here's the final working code:

Here's CurrentStatus:

```
class CurrentStatus
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  STATUSES = %w"DRAFT LIVE SUSPENDED"
  attr_reader :status

  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => STATUSES

  def initialize(status)
    @status = status.to_s
  end

  def self.valid_statuses
    STATUSES.to_a
  end

  def self.to_a
    self.valid_statuses
  end

  def to_s
    @status.to_s
  end
end
```

And Interests.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: interests
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  description :text
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  status_key  :string(255)
#

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :status_key, :status

  validate :valid_status

  def status
    return CurrentStatus.new(status_key)
  end

  def status=(value)
    self.status_key = value
  end

  private
  def valid_status
    errors.add(:status_key, "is invalid") unless status.valid?
  end

end
```

This code allows me to say `Interests.create(status: 'INVALID_STATUS')` and the system will prevent save while allowing through `Interests.create(status: 'LIVE')`.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to use ActiveModel validations
These should be triggered, then, when the overall `Interest` model attempts to be saved.

```
class CurrentStatus
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  STATUSES = %w(DRAFT LIVE INACTIVE)
  attr_reader :status

  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => STATUSES

  def initialize(status)
    stringed_status = status.to_s
    @status = status.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, that's what I was originally thought to do, but since it's effective the same behavior on both objects I wanted to try and DRY it up.

Comment: Sorry, just read it more closely.  Hmm... I was trying to avoid including any 'Active' modules to keep the class as light as possible, but you're right in that might save me the most grief.  Let me try it out!